# MYSQL - Return the complete row with the maximum value for a group and join it to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm currently currently having trouble with a MYSQL query. I searched through many stackoverflow questions looking for the answer but couldnt find one.

THE PROBLEM:
I have two tables -

teams = |id (primary key)|name|sigma|mu|

ranks = |match_id|team_id|mu|sigma|

the teams table contains the team_id,name aswell as sigma and mu (more on that later). teams.id also functions as a foreign key for team_id in ranks. Ranks contains both a match id and team id aswell as mu and sigma.

Basically i want to find the largest match id for each team id and assign the corresponding mu and sigma (from the ranks table) to the correct team in the teams table. In other words i want each team in the teams table to have the sigma and mu value corresponding to the largest match_id.

I tried the MYSQL command below:

```
-- these will serve as the basis for the procdures which update the teams...
SELECT
  MAX(ranks.match_id) as max_match,
  ranks.team_id as team_id,
  teams.id,
  teams.name,
  ranks.match_id,
  ranks.team_id,
FROM
  ranks
  JOIN teams ON teams.id = team_id
UPDATE
  teams
SET
  teams.mu = ranks.mu, teams.sigma = ranks.sigma
WHERE
  max_match = ranks.match_id
  AND team_id = ranks.team_id
```

Doing this i get an error. Thanks in advance for the help.

Also I'm worried that me not being able to do this could be caused by a major error in my understanding in MYSQL, so any help explaining where i went wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding sample table data to your question would make it more easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to `update` teams with the most "recent" mu and sigma values.  You can use `update` with a `join` and window functions:

```
update teams t join
       (select r.*,
               row_number() over (partition by team_id order by match_id desc) as seqnum
        from ranks r
       ) r
       using (team_id)
    set t.mu = r.mu,
        t.sigma = r.sigma
    where seqnum = 1;
```